# Generating color ranges in Python

Tags: python, colors

I want to generate a list of color specifications in the form of (r, g, b) tuples, that span the entire color spectrum with as many entries as I want. So for 5 entries I would want something like:

- (0, 0, 1)
- (0, 1, 0)
- (1, 0, 0)
- (1, 0.5, 1)
- (0, 0, 0.5)

Of course, if there are more entries than combination of 0 and 1 it should turn to use fractions, etc. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the HSV/HSB/HSL color space (three names for more or less the same thing). Generate N tuples equally spread in hue space, then just convert them to RGB.

Sample code:

```
import colorsys
N = 5
HSV_tuples = [(x*1.0/N, 0.5, 0.5) for x in range(N)]
RGB_tuples = map(lambda x: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*x), HSV_tuples)
```

Comment: Cool, then using colorsys.hsv_to_rgb I get exactly what I need :).
[colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(x*1.0/N, 0.5, 0.5) for x in range(N)].

Comment: if you want to use an index in `RGB_tuples`, in Python 3 you must make a `list` out of the `map`, which is a generator, simply by `list(map(lambda...))`

Comment: in Python 3 you don't need `x*1.0/N`, `x/N` always produces a float result. To get an integer result you would need to do `x//N`

Comment: those `0.5`s can be replaced by other values. HSV tuples are (hue, saturation, value) tuples, with all tuple elements in the range from 0 to 1, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score 44):

Color palettes are interesting. Did you know that the same brightness of, say, green, is perceived more intensely than, say, red? Have a look at http://poynton.ca/PDFs/ColorFAQ.pdf. If you would like to use preconfigured palettes, have a look at [seaborn's palettes](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
palette = sns.color_palette(None, 3)
```

Generates 3 colors from the current palette.

Comment: IMHO this is better than the accepted answer because the colors in the palette are distinctive. The HSV method generates colors that are hard to tell apart.

Comment: Yes, I 100% agree! This is much more modular and concise than the method presented in the accepted answer.

Comment: The palettes generated by Seaborn look great. I just wish it didn't depend on Matplotlib, which is a beast.

Comment: An entire paper on nothing but color theory, but not a single color in the entire article! Impresive.

Answer (score 14):

Following the steps of kquinn's and jhrf :)

For Python 3 it can be done the following way:

```
def get_N_HexCol(N=5):
    HSV_tuples = [(x * 1.0 / N, 0.5, 0.5) for x in range(N)]
    hex_out = []
    for rgb in HSV_tuples:
        rgb = map(lambda x: int(x * 255), colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*rgb))
        hex_out.append('#%02x%02x%02x' % tuple(rgb))
    return hex_out
```

Answer (score 12):

I created the following function based on [kquinn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54486/kquinn) answer.

```py
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb
    
def get_hex_color_list(num_colors=5, saturation=1.0, value=1.0):
    hex_colors = []
    hsv_colors = [[float(x / num_colors), saturation, value] for x in range(num_colors)]
    
    for hsv in hsv_colors:
       hsv = [int(x * 255) for x in hsv_to_rgb(*hsv)]
    
       # Formatted as hexadecimal string using the ':02x' format specifier
       hex_colors.append(f"#{hsv[0]:02x}{hsv[1]:02x}{hsv[2]:02x}")
    
    return hex_colors
```

Comment: I was searching for this (y). But in my case there was no much light after I saw adding them to form a spectrum. The output looks like this [Spectrum](https://postimg.org/image/qspiz6c4h/)
I need to have some more brightness on it.

Comment: The hsv space is hue, saturation, value, so a saturation closer to 1 will make stronger colours and a value closer to 1 will higher the brightness.

Comment: Anybody know the best way to update this to Py3? Something like: `hex_out.append("".join(list(map(lambda x: chr(x)[2:], rgb))))`?

Answer (score 4):

However many number of colors you need and very simple.

```
from matplotlib import cm
n_colors = 10
colours = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, n_colors))
```