# How to plot with 20 different color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I want to plot `20 newsgroup dataset` topics using matplotlib. I have writted the code below:

```
markers = ["o", "v", "8", "s", "p", "*", "h", "H", "+", "x", "D"]
    plt.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':10})
    classes_to_visual = list(set(classes_to_visual))
    C = len(classes_to_visual)
    while True:
        if C <= len(markers):
            break
        markers += markers

    class_ids = dict(zip(classes_to_visual, range(C)))

    if isinstance(doc_codes, dict) and isinstance(doc_labels, dict):
        codes, labels = zip(*[(code, doc_labels[doc]) for doc, code in doc_codes.items() if doc_labels[doc] in classes_to_visual])
    else:
        codes, labels = doc_codes, doc_labels

    X = np.r_[list(codes)]
    tsne = TSNE(perplexity=40, n_components=2, init='pca', n_iter=5000)
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    X = tsne.fit_transform(X)
    # NUM_COLORS = 20
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), facecolor='white')

    for c in classes_to_visual:
        idx = np.array(labels) == c
        plt.plot(X[idx, 0], X[idx, 1], linestyle='None', alpha=1, marker=markers[class_ids[c]],
                 markersize=10, label=c)
    legend = plt.legend(loc='upper right', shadow=True)
    plt.savefig(save_file, format='eps', dpi=2000)
    plt.show()
```

My only problem is that it plotted the 20 news group using `11` main colors and for distinguishing others it has `markers`. but I want to have different distinguishable colors.

I tried various ways like defining colors:

```
ax.set_color_cycle([cm(1. * i / NUM_COLORS) for i in range(NUM_COLORS)])
```

though in some cases the colors was only different shade and did not differ that much!!

What can I do to get it work properly?
so far this is the result:
[image]

Comment: This might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806598/matplotlib-set-color-cycle-versus-set-prop-cycle

Comment: Please separate: Do you need help getting 20 colors or do you need help getting those colors into the color cycle?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Actually I need to get 20 different colors, if you look at my figure, for example, blue has been repeated for two different categories but by different markers. what I need is only have differently distinguishable colors

Comment: @anushka the problem with that link is that it follows the order. for example, in some case, it might show the figure with different shades of blue, green, pink which those shades are very similar such that hardly can be differentiated

Comment: Some reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389636/creating-over-20-unique-legend-colors-using-matplotlib), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876853/generating-color-ranges-in-python), , or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697933/colormap-with-maximum-distinguishable-colours) or more generally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470690/how-to-automatically-generate-n-distinct-colors)

Comment: Thank you so much, I am trying the third link. do you know how can I incorporate the `ax` in the code above?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Actually I spent some time though not able to get it run. the first link does not work on my case as it will assign colors in order. for example all shades of green red .. so that the figure I get again the colors are not that much distinctable. the third link I could not incorporate in my code :!

Comment: I mean there is no magic function that gives you the colors you want. You need to create a list/array of those colors. If unhappy with existing solutions, just type them up like `["red", "green", "salmon", "navy", ....]`

Comment: But I did not find anywhere in matplotlib that you can specify a list of coulurs manually? Do you mind expaining according to the code I have where can I put this list of colors?

Comment: Still did not find any solution :(. I tried to give a list of colours to `c arument` in matplotlib byt it throws an error `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument:` . Do you have any ide of this? I appreciate if you could help me fix this:)

Comment: The aim is to change the property cycle to use those colors. Check the links provided in the comment from 4 days ago.

Comment: Well, fixed :), any idea how can we have the legend but making sure not overlapped with the figure? I put legend of 20 categories name upper righ but still overlap with figure.